# GIMP Color to Alpha removes color

Tags: gimp

In GIMP, when I use "Color to Alpha" to remove the dull blue background of this image: 
[image: dull blue]

It removes some blue from the entire image, so most of the image looks slightly transparent:

[image: dull blue]
How can I stop this so that only "the dull blue" is removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a selection so that color-to-alpha is only applied where needed:

- using the fuzzy selection, select the background. Shift-click any closed areas (inside of 'O','P','D,'A', etc....) to add it
- Select>Grow by 2 pixels to include all the edge pixels in the selection
- *Color>Color to alpha*.

PS; You have strange artifacts around the big squares (the background isn't as uniform as it looks) so using C2A alone will leave some opacity in the background. A more complete approach can be:

- Make fuzzy selection as above
- Save selection to channel
- Select>Shrink by 2 pixels and [delete]. This insure that the background is completely clean
- Restore original selection from channel
- *Select>Grow* by 2px and C2A.

This more complete method is partially automated in the [ofn-erase-background](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/) script.